# Copy paste loop a number of times as the cell value - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a loop to copy and paste a range of cells from one excel worksheet to another a number of times, as specified in a cell A1.

```
    Sub AnalogPointBuild()

                Dim i As Integer
                Dim y As Integer

                'only copy the number of times as the count in cell A1 of worksheet "inputs"
                Sheets("inputs").Activate
                y = Range("A1").Value

                ' copy the range of cells from one worksheet "Analog Template' to the "Analog Output"        

                For i = 1 To y
                Worksheets("Analog Template").Range("B3:EU3").Copy Worksheets("Analog Output").Range("B3:EU3")
                Next i

    End Sub
```

I understand that during the iteration, the paste does not increment the cell value and paste it in the next one down.

Help! What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are not changing your paste destination. Plus you don't need to loop (or copy and paste) - use Resize.

Comment: Watch what happens if you use F8 to step through your code as the for loop executes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, as per comments above.

```
Sub AnalogPointBuild()

Dim y As Long

'only copy the number of times as the count in cell A1 of worksheet "inputs"
y = Sheets("inputs").Range("A1").Value

' copy the range of cells from one worksheet "Analog Template' to the "Analog Output"
Worksheets("Analog Output").Range("B3:EU3").Resize(y).Value = Worksheets("Analog Template").Range("B3:EU3").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I did not know about the resize property! Much appreciated, thank you, @SJR!

Comment: Very useful it is. Use it whenever you can!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop, rather you can try it like this...

```
Sub AnalogPointBuild()
    Dim y As Integer

    'only copy the number of times as the count in cell A1 of worksheet "inputs"
    y = Sheets("inputs").Range("A1").Value

    ' copy the range of cells from one worksheet "Analog Template' to the "Analog Output"

    Worksheets("Analog Template").Range("B3:EU3").Copy Worksheets("Analog Output").Range("B3:EU3").Resize(y)

End Sub
```